# Blender2.8 freezes when using smooth brush

Tags: sculpting

lastly I can't work properly, after few strokes with smooth brush blender just stops working for like 5-8s, it happens very often.

My specs: 
System Windows10 64bit 
16GB RAM 
processor Intel core i7-8750H 2.20GHz 
Graphic card GTX 1070

I usually work on like 1milion faces without dyntopo.
My pc can handle these models in edit mode, but smoothing in sculting mode is lagging, please I need help

Already tried:
Reinstalling Blender 2.8 to newest version,
Decimating my model to at least half polygons count,
Also for some reasons I can't open my model in 2.79 version, even without UI loaded.

Comment: You obviously can't open a Blender 2.80 Beta scene in Blender 2.79, because Blender 2.80 uses a different file format. Select your object, export it to .obj, then import that .obj into Blender 2.79

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but in multires. Using airbrush stroke method instead of space increased performance.